# I Provided Correct Reference For manifest.json File But In Chrome Dev Tool It Says No Manifest Detected

Tags: progressive-web-apps

[image]

I Gave Link Of Manifest.json Correctly But In Google Dev Tools It is Not Detected ????

Comment: Have you tried updating your chrome version? What action are you trying to do when the error occurs? Have you visited the [PWA debugging documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/progressive-web-apps)?

Comment: Can you load the manifest file directly in the browser?